# Problem while using SymPY's dsolve to solve differential equation of criticaly damped oscilator

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I have been trying to write a program which will take a set of values and initial conditions for harmonic oscillator, solve the differential equation and display the function of the phi(t).

```
import sympy as sp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = sp.Symbol("t")
phi = sp.Function('phi')

#Values of the oscilator
beta = 0.4
omega_0 = 0.4
f0 = 0
omega = 0

#Initial conditions
phi_0 = 3.14/4
v_phi_0 = 0

#phi''(t) + 2*beta*phi'(t) + omega_0^2*phi(t) - f0*sin(omega*t) = 0
eq = sp.diff(phi(t),t,2)+2*beta*sp.diff(phi(t),t)+omega_0**2*phi(t)-f0*sp.sin(omega*t)
print(sp.dsolve(eq))
equation = sp.dsolve(eq,ics={phi(0):phi_0,sp.diff(phi(t),t).subs(t,0):v_phi_0})
print(equation)
wzor = sp.lambdify(t,equation.rhs,"numpy")
xvals = np.arange(0,30,.1)
yvals = wzor(xvals)

# make figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(xvals, yvals)
ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('phi(t)')
plt.show()
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but when the values of `beta` and `omega_0` are equal (so called critical damping) **and** are lower than 1, the program  appears to be solving the equation wrongly.

```
Eq(phi(t), (C1*sin(3.65002571393103e-9*t) + C2*sin(3.6500259065127e-9*t) + C3*cos(3.65002571393103e-9*t) + C4*cos(3.6500259065127e-9*t))*exp(-0.4*t))
```

In other cases, including when `beta` and `omega_0` are equal and higher than 1, there are only 2 constants `C1` and `C2` after solving the differential equation, but in this case there are 4, which shouldn't be happening. Because of this, the program can't continue and draw the plot, because of these 2 additional constants that I can't solve for.

```
ax.plot(xvals, yvals)

TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Edit: Also, when a drive force is applied, so `f0` and `omega` are different from 0, following error occurs

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot find 2 solutions to the homogeneous equation necessary to apply undetermined coefficients to 0.16*phi(t) - 5*sin(0.4*t) + 0.8*Derivative(phi(t), t) + Derivative(phi(t), (t, 2)) (number of terms != order)
```

It's probably connected to the main problem, but I thought it's good to mention.

Edit 2: Other problems begin to appear when `beta` and `omega_0` are equal and bigger than 3, but are also decimal. No problems appears when they are whole numbers.

Comment: The frequencies are essentially zero, their non-zero values are artifacts of the floating-point number format. With a perturbation of a double root one can expect errors of about the square roots of the machine precision. That there are four roots is possibly a consequence of some Laplace transform technique. It is better in symbolic calculations to work with only symbolic constants or rational numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbolic computation and floating point constants do not go well or at all together. One simple fix is to replace all the constants by rational numbers using the sympy `Rational` data type,

```
#Values of the oscilator
beta = sp.Rational(2,5)
omega_0 = sp.Rational(2,5)
f0 = 0
omega = 0

#Initial conditions
phi_0 = sp.Rational(314,400)
v_phi_0 = 0
```

With only these changes, the output is correctly

```
Eq(phi(t), (C1 + C2*t)*exp(-2*t/5))
Eq(phi(t), (157*t/500 + 157/200)*exp(-2*t/5))
```

and the plot is produces as

[image]